# How to set default time for a TIME column in table MySQL 5.7?

Tags: mysql

I want to set the default value in a TIME column in a MySQL DB table to be '08:00:00' regardless of timezone. I can't quite figure out the syntax.

`create table venues (venue_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, name VARCHAR(100), address VARCHAR(250), open_time TIME DEFAULT '08:00:00'::TIME, close_time TIME DEFAULT '20:00:00'::TIME, activities VARCHAR(250);`

It has a problem with how i'm trying to set the default values for the two TIME columns. I also tried using `'08:00:00'::time without time zone`

Comment: You are missing a closing `)` in your query.

Comment: CREATE TABLE venues (venue_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, name VARCHAR(100), address VARCHAR(150), activities VARCHAR(150), open_time TIME DEFAULT '08:00:00'::TIME, close_time TIME DEFAULT '20:00:00'::TIME);  Still having a syntax issue. EDIT: figured it out, don't need the ::TIME casts

Comment: Looks like Postgres to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`'08:00:00'::TIME` is how you do a type cast in Postgres, not MySQL. MySQL uses the SQL standard [`cast`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/cast-functions.html#function_cast). Similarly `time without time zone` is a Postgres type.

You don't need a type cast at all, MySQL (and Postgres) will cast it to the column type.

```
create table venues (
    venue_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(100),
    address VARCHAR(250),
    open_time TIME DEFAULT '08:00:00',
    close_time TIME DEFAULT '20:00:00',
    activities VARCHAR(250)
);
```

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=fa1285be7f2a7b5f5cafcdf45aa0a2ff)

Answer (score 0):

::TIME casts are not needed for the TIME columns